# Table of Contents not showing up in LaTeXbase

Tags: table-of-contents, online

I am trying to make a table of contents exactly as instructed on the tutorial, but it does not show up, even when I compile 2 times.
The tutorial uses this code as an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Section}

Dummy text

\subsection{Subsection}

Dummy text

\end{document}
```

And it should output this:
[image: nd]

But in my document after compiling twice, only the "Contents" header shows up on the first page and sections I added on the second page.
[image]
[image]

I also tried using the `\addtocontents{toc}` and `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}` commands but they don't do anything.
How do I make the contents appear, including the page numbers of each section as shown in the tutorial?

Comment: I clarified that this is happening after I compiled it twice.

Comment: The MWE that you have provided worked well on my system. Which TeX-engine are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll let LaTeX answer the question:

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\def\latexbase{\LaTeX base doesn't support table of contents}
\begin{document}
\latexbase
\makeatletter
  \immediate\write\@auxout
    {\gdef\noexpand\latexbase{\noexpand\LaTeX base supports table of contents}}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

(as always, compile twice).

---

LaTeXbase doesn't seem to keep track of auxiliary files, such as the `.toc` for the Table of Contents, or even the `.aux` file. Plus, the log file there says:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (TeX Live 2010)
```

so for those who complain that Overleaf's TeXLive distribution is outdated (2017)...

The solution is to move to another platform (Overleaf, for example), or better, have a local installation.

Comment: Thank you. I just tried it in Overleaf and it worked.

Comment: Note they are not using an off the shelf  texlive distribution but compiling the tex sources to javascript and running it in a browser so they can perhaps be forgiven not for updating too often (aux files ought to work though....)